# Azure Function : Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service while trying to access Azure Key vault

Tags: azure, azure-functions, firewall, azure-keyvault

I have a keyvault in which I have the secrets. I have an Azure function app with a system-assigned identity that has 'Get' secret access on this keyvault.

Below is my function code

```
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # Get a credential object using Managed Identity
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

    # Create a SecretClient using the Key Vault URL and credential
    vault_url = "https://xxxx.vault.azure.net/"
    secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=credential)

    # Retrieve the secret from Key Vault
    try:
        secret_value = secret_client.get_secret("xxxx").value
        response_message = {"message": f"Secret retrieved from Key Vault: {secret_value}"}
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_message), mimetype="application/json")
    except Exception as e:
        response_message = {"error": str(e)}
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_message), status_code=500, mimetype="application/json")
```

and below is the firewall configuration on the keyvault
[image]

[image]

```
{
"error": "(Forbidden) Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.\r\nClient address: 51.xx.xx.46\r\nCaller:....Code: Forbidden\nMessage: Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.\r\nClient address: 51.xx.xx.46\r\nCaller: ..Inner error: {\n    \"code\": \"ForbiddenByFirewall\"\n}"
}
```

Comment: Are your Key vault and azure functions in the same region? is there any specific network configuration between keyvault and azure function?

Comment: Both are in the same region and there is no specific network configuration.

Comment: Can you try adding the function app outgoing address in allowed list of IP Addresses?

Comment: How /where can I find it?

Comment: az functionapp show --resource-group <GROUP_NAME> --name <APP_NAME> --query outboundIpAddresses --output tsv
az functionapp show --resource-group <GROUP_NAME> --name <APP_NAME> --query possibleOutboundIpAddresses --output tsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daredevil Thanks for the comments.

***Make sure to add your IP address in the firewall settings.***

I added the above IP address to the key vault firewall settings as below:

[image]
[image]

**Code** :

```py
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

    vault_url = "https://<keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net/"
    secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=credential)

    try:
        secret_value = secret_client.get_secret("<secret_name>").value
        response_message = {"message": f"Secret retrieved from Key Vault: {secret_value}"}
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_message), mimetype="application/json")
    except Exception as e:
        response_message = {"error": str(e)}
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_message), status_code=500, mimetype="application/json")
```

***requirements.txt*** :

```py
azure-functions
azure-identity
azure-keyvault-secrets
```

***Output*** :

It ran successfully as below,

[image]
[image]

***Browser output*** :

[image]

Then, I deployed the above code to the function app as below:

[image]

**Azure Portal** :

[image]

I added the above **IP address** to the key vault below,

[image]

**Azure Portal Output** :

It runs successfully and retrived the secret from the key avault as below.

[image]