# Azure Key Vault Logs: Success with Forbidden ResultSignature

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I'm analyzing Azure Key Vault logs and have come across an interesting situation. My query is looking for any Forbidden
access attempts to the Key Vault, and I'm trying to understand why some entries show

ResultType: Success
but also have

ResultSignature: Forbidden
Here's the query I used:

AzureDiagnostics | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT" | where ResultSignature == "Forbidden" | order by TimeGenerated desc | take 300
Despite these logs, the web app seems to retrieve secrets just fine. Can anyone explain why a Forbidden
result would also be marked as a Success? Here is example of error from log analytics

TenantId
xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx

TimeGenerated [UTC]
2024-03-20T20:04:53.0973838Z

ResourceId
/SUBSCRIPTIONS/xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx/RESOURCEGROUPS/RG-1/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT/VAULTS/KEYVAULT001

Category
AuditEvent

ResourceGroup
RG-1

SubscriptionId
xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx

ResourceProvider
MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT

Resource
KEYVAULT001

ResourceType
VAULTS

OperationName
SecretGet

ResultType
Success

CorrelationId
xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx

ResultDescription
Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.
Client address: 20.100.100.1
Caller: appid=xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx;oid=xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx;iss=https://sts.windows.net/xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx/;xms_mirid=/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx/resourcegroups/rg-1/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/id-managed;xms_az_rid=/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx/resourcegroups/rg-1/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/id-managed
Vault: KEYVAULT001;location=westeurope

requestUri_s
https://KEYVAULT001.vault.azure.net/secrets/GitlabContainerRegistryUsername/?api-version=7.0

DurationMs
17

CallerIPAddress
20.100.100.1

OperationVersion
7.0

ResultSignature
Forbidden

id_s
https://KEYVAULT001.vault.azure.net/secrets/GitlabContainerRegistryUsername

httpStatusCode_d
403

identity_claim_appid_g
xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx

isAccessPolicyMatch_b
true

SourceSystem
Azure

identity_claim_xms_az_nwperimid_s
[]

identity_claim_appidacr_s
2

tlsVersion_s
TLS1_2

identity_claim_oid_g
xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx

identity_claim_xms_mirid_s
/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/rg-1/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/id-managed

At first i thought it might be networking issue but both keyvault and webapp are in the same subnet and since webapp can retrieve secrets then it is not networking issue, still since i have this error in log analytics for all our environments it is concerning.

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376410/azure-function-client-address-is-not-authorized-and-caller-is-not-a-trusted-se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm analyzing Azure Key Vault logs and have come across an interesting situation. My query is looking for any Forbidden access attempts to the Key Vault, and I'm trying to understand why some entries show
> ResultType: Success but also have
> ResultSignature: Forbidden

The reason for the **ResultType: Success** in the `Log Analytics` entry indicates that the operation to retrieve logs was completed successfully, and it is not related to the error and **ResultSignature: Forbidden** indicates that the operation was not authorized. This means that the operation was successful in the sense that it was completed, but it was not authorized to access the resource.

**Output:**

[image]

The above error message indicates that the client address **49.37.154.218** is not authorized access to **Key vault**.

To resolve the issue, make sure to add the client address: **49.37.154.218** in `Azure key` vault by navigating to below step.

1. Go to **Azure key vault > Networking > Firewalls and virtual networks > Firewall**

> Note: If you choose 2nd option, include your **Public IP** under the firewall settings to access the **Key Vault** with same IP.

[image]

After adding the client's IP address, **49.37.154.218**, to the `Key Vault`, access will be granted from that IP.